# Altering the back behaviour in the browser PHP

Tags: php, session, browser

In my PHP site, when a user adds something to their cart I trigger a URL change to make some functions and triggers on the page:

Original URL

```
/category/product/10
```

New URL

```
/category/product/10#addtocartbutton
```

URL becomes

```
/category/product/10?x=1
```

The method:

```
/category/product/10
/category/product/10#addtocartbutton (user clicks an onclick href to submit form)
/category/product/10?x=1 (the form adds the item to the session and appends this URL querystring)
```

The problem is when they press the bac b

Comment: So is your new URl `/category/product/10#addtocartbutton` or `/category/product/10?x=1`?

Comment: Do not attempt to do this. If you can, redesign the application such that whenever a user does press the back button and resubmits the form, nothing bad will happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Javascript`, using `location.replace` instead of `location.href = 'new location'`
Take a look at: http://www.roseindia.net/javascript/javascript-location-replace.shtml
-> `location.replace` will replace the current address by the new one -> when user click back button -> error will not happen.

Answer (score 0):

Or try something with [pushState](http://badassjs.com/post/840846392/location-hash-is-dead-long-live-html5-pushstate). You should be able to manipulate you're history according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

A good idea is to make the add function redirect you back to the product page without showing the query-string. Since I dont know how you wrote your add controller it's hard to give you an exact code example...

Write the PHP controller for adding something like:

```
function add_to_cart()
{
  add $_GET['x'] to session;
  redirect back to product page;
}
```